# Using CharInSet in Delphi or Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How do I use `CharInSet()` to get rid of this warning?

```
lastop:=c;
{OK - if op is * or / and prev op was + or -, put the whole thing in parens}
If (c in ['*','/']) and (NextToLastOp in ['+','-']) then
  Result.text:='('+Result.text+')';
Result.text:=Result.text+c;
```

> [dcc32 Warning] U_Calc1.pas(114): W1050 WideChar reduced to byte char in set expressions.  Consider using 'CharInSet' function in 'SysUtils' unit.

Comment: Start with the documentation!

Comment: Wow! gr8 answer

Comment: Well, if you had read the documentation, it would have been obvious how to call the function. You did look at the documentation right?

Comment: @David Heffernan The documentation isn't always clear, especially for beginners.

Comment: The official documentation doesn't even have an example of using charinset. This is therefore a reasonable question to ask.

Answer (score 15):

**CharInSet** is necessary due to the fact that **WideChar** values are too large to be used in actual set operations.

To use it in your code you would use it like this:

```
If (CharInSet(c, ['*','/']) and (CharInSet(NextToLastOp, ['+','-']) then
```

However **CharInSet** doesn't actually do anything special or even useful other than silence the warning.

The code in the function is identical to the code it replaces.  The warning is silenced only because the RTL units are pre-compiled.  The compiler does not recompile them even if you do a full "*Rebuild all*".  i.e. that code in `SysUtils` is not actually ever re-compiled.  If it were it would emit the exact same warning.

So, you could use that function to avoid the warning but if you can be certain that your character data is ASCII (or extended ASCII), that is with ordinal values in the range #0 to #255, then you could also avoid the warning by typecasting your character variable explicitly to an ANSIChar:

```
If (ANSIChar(c) in ['*','/']) and (ANSIChar(NextToLastOp) in ['+','-']) then
```

**To reiterate:**  You should **only** do this if you are *absolutely certain* that the character data that you are working with consists *only* of ASCII characters.

But this same caveat applies equally to using **CharInSet** since this *still* requires that you test for membership in an **ANSIChar** set (i.e. single byte characters).

Explicit type-casting has the advantage (imho) of making it explicit and apparent that your code is intended *deliberately* to expect and work only with ASCII characters, rather than giving a perhaps misleading impression of being more fully equipped to handle Unicode.

Comment: The cleanest way to handle such a test is to write `(c='*') or (c='/')`

Comment: procedure TForm3.Btn0Click(Sender: TObject);
{handles all digits}
begin
{NOTE! 4th charatcer of button anme is the digit - do NOT rename buttons!}
 If sender is TButton
 then If TButton(Sender).name[4] in ['0'..'9']
    then AddDigit(TButton(sender).name[4])
    else beep;
end;[dcc32 Warning] Unit3.pas(119): W1050 WideChar reduced to byte char in set expressions.  Consider using 'CharInSet' function in 'SysUtils' unit.

Comment: @Raj: This is the very same problem, isn't it?

Comment: @Raj Using component names like that is very brittle, there is almost always a better way.

Comment: Guide me wirh a example.

Comment: AddDigit(TButton(sender).name[4]) . How to use charinset for this syntax. Iam trying but not getting the right way to implement this.

Comment: @Deltics But you end up with code that works, unlike your code which fails with ordinals > 255. And it is trivially easy to wrap these comparisons up in a way to make the calling code less noisy. For instance by passing an open array parameter of characters to a function that iterates over them performing the comparison.

Comment: I think it is cleaner. Surely you know how to extract code into a method? I know you do. Anyway, your answer is factually wrong. Consider this program: `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

const
  c = #7796;

begin
  Writeln(CharInSet(c, ['t']));
  Writeln(AnsiChar(c) in ['t']);
end.
`  The output is `FALSE TRUE`

Comment: Further, the fact that I did not answer the question does not render my comments invalid. It is commonplace here to comment without answering. I'm sure you know that. You yourself do it.

Comment: @Raj Hard to give an example of how to do it better, without knowing more details of what the problem is. But I don't think I've ever seen a problem that has best been solved using component names. The problem is that it is all too easy to change the names, and not find all the code that depends upon those names.

Comment: @Deltics Nope. You stated that `CharInSet(c, [...])` is identical to `AnsiChar(c) in [...]`. That statement is wrong, as the program in my comment demonstrates.

Comment: *The difference is that CharInSet might give the impression of correctly supporting a test for WideChar encoded values in an ANSIChar set when it does not.*  Again, that statement is wrong.

Comment: *You should only do this if you are certain that the character data that you are working with is certain to consist of ASCII characters.

But this same caveat applies equally to using CharInSet.* Also wrong.

Comment: Look closely at the program I provided in the comment. Look at the output. Explain to me why the two tests evaluate to different values when you claim they should always evaluate to the same value. Either both false or both true.

Comment: @David - you know what, I'm done playing your game.  Maybe CharInset works differently, or maybe they fixed it in the version you are working with.  Either way, how about you write up a better answer or use your moderator power to edit and improve this one instead of snarking around in the comments ?

Comment: Look at what the compiler does with `C in CharSet` in the implementation of `CharInSet`. It emits code like this: `Project86.dpr.10: Result := C in CharSet;
004051B1 8B45F8           mov eax,[ebp-$08]
004051B4 668B55FE         mov dx,[ebp-$02]
004051B8 6681FAFF00       cmp dx,$00ff
004051BD 7709             jnbe $004051c8
004051BF 81E2FF000000     and edx,$000000ff
004051C5 0FA310           bt [eax],edx
004051C8 0F92C0           setb al
004051CB 8845F7           mov [ebp-$09],al` Look at that `cmp dx,$00ff`. You don't get that with your cast to `AnsiChar`.

Comment: I'm not playing a game for heaven's sake. You made a mistake. I pointed it out. Try to get past your pride! You accuse me of "always being right" and being "drunk". Well, I think perhaps you need to look harder in the mirror. We all make mistakes. So what. If you can't admit it when you made a mistake, what are you?

Comment: Now, knowing what I know now about `CharInSet`, I think it has value. If the sets elements are all ASCII then it is the cleanest way to write this code. So, I take back my first comment. I'd only stand by that if you needed to work with sets containing non ASCII characters.

Comment: This is the place to Help those who are in need. Not to play PRIDE AND PRIJIDUCE.No one is forcing anyone to help or guide. Its your choice man. So be free and think free.

Comment: What made you think anybody was being forced to do anything. I pointed out the errors in this answer. Do what you will with that information.